# How to sum up the child values that starts from child to root in a tree structure?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, tree, skeleton-code

I want to get the absolute values of each node. Absolute value meaning that the distance from the root.

if I have a skeleton model.

the root childs are

```
root
left hip - child
left knee - child
left foot - child

assume that all the bones lengths are equal to 1.
root to hip = 1
hip to knee = 1
knee to foot = 1
```

So if I want to get the position of foot joint from the root, it should be 3. am I right?

```
root to foot = root to hip + hip to knee + knee to foot = 3
```

so these are the subroutines I am using..

```
void ComputeAbs()
{
    for(unsigned int i=1; i<nNodes(); i++) 
    {
        node* b = getNode(i);
        if(b)
        {
            b->nb = ComputeAbsSum(b);
        }
    }
}

int ComputeAbsSum(node *b)
{
    int m = b->nb;
    if (b->child != NULL) 
    {
        m *= ComputeAbsSum(b->child);
    }
    return m;
}
```

the output would be like

```
root to hip = 3
root to knee = 2
root to foot = 1

But I want in a reverse way, i should get like this

root to hip = 1
root to knee = 2
root to foot = 3
```

How can I achieve this result? how to add tree childs values starts from child to root?

the final objective is to get the final pose by calculating the absolute transformation of a joint.

```
bonePoseAbsolute[i] = bonePoseAbsolute[parentIndex] * bonePoseRelative[i];
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are some serious flaws. First, from where can one get the edge cost? Is it always unit? Then the solution from Kane@ is correct.

Please specify how to get the edge cost between b and b->child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem in your recursion.  Try

```
int ComputeAbsSum(node *b)
{
    int result = 1;
    if (b->child != NULL)
        result += ComputeAbsSum(b->child);
    return result;
}
```

*edit: if you want to traverse the tree in reverse,

```
int ComputeAbsSumReverse(node *b)
{
    int result = 1;
    if (b->parent != NULL)
        result += ComputeAbsSum(b->parent);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: No Kane, It just counts the number of childs. I do not want counting of childs in a tree. I want to add up the values of all parents to the specific child. For example, foot has knee parent and knee has hip parent, so the footchild->value += kneeparent->value+hipparent->value.

Comment: based on your comment, replace int result = 1 with int result = b->value

Comment: Yes I am already doing this using this function int ComputeAbsSum(node *b)... you can see that. This function adds the from root to child, meaning that it adds all the childs values and store into the parent. For example hip += knee+foot, then knee+=foot, but I want in a reverse way, foot+=knee+hip, and knee+=hip.. like that. What I want is same like this std::reverse(vector.begin(), vector.end()); but the issue is with this kind of list in which you have parent and child relationship, how can I go from child to parent? parent to child is easy but child to parent?

Comment: In the node class, include a pointer to the parent(s).  Then in my answer, change b->child to b->parent